# Can't build the project with Holo Everywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere, holoeverywhere

All I did was to add `HoloEverywhere Library` as a library to my project and change in the manifest

from `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >`

to `android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >`

Now I can't run my project, I get:

```
[2014-07-14 14:17:26 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-07-14 14:17:26 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I have no idea what it means or how to fix it. It runs perfectly without HoloEverywhere.

PS: Just so you don't ask, HoloEverywhere is marked as a library, both that and my project are built with 4.4.2. I'm using some other libraries as well, but shouldn't interfere as those are not much for UI.

**Edit:** Checking some other questions like mine, I think I have to remove one of the android-support-v4 from lib. But which one?

- my project has `android-support-v4.jar` in lib
- another library I'm using has `android-support-v4.jar` in its lib
  folder and these 2 worked perfectly before, as I mentioned
- HoloEverywhere has `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` in its lib folder

Comment: This problem also happened if you have multiple version of libraries included in your build path physically. Removing the unused libraries from libs path, clean and save the project, restarts Eclipse and recompile it again do working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting all `android-support-v4.jar` from all projects/libraries and only leave `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` in HoloEverywhere. If eclipse says `android-support-v4.jar` is necessary in any library/project, just put `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` instead.

I guess `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` is a custom library built on top of `android-support-v4.jar`, so it includes everything and more.